# Send fields along with Json Array through retrofit2 call

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

```
API URL : BASE_URL/student/savestudenttestreport
METHOD : POST
PARAMETER TO PASS:

INPUT:
school_id:4
tabID:582328062112255
student_id:190
student_test_history_id:236
all_student_report: {"studentlist_id": "4",
                      "maths": "78",
                    },
             {"studentlist_id": "5",
                "Engish": "65",
                 "Science": "98"
        }



OUTPUT:
{
    "status": true,
    "result": {
        "student_test_history_id": "236",
        "student_test_report": "\"studentlist_id\": \"4\",\n            \"maths\": \"78\",\n \"studentlist_id\": \"4\",\n  \"Engish\": \"65\",\n            \"studentlist_id\": \"4\""
    },
    "message": "Report saved successfully!"
}
Errors:
1)
    {
        "status": false,
        "message":  "SchoolID should not empty!" 
     }
2)
    {
        "status": false,
        "message": "Tablet ID should not empty!"
}
3)
    {
        "status": false,
        "message": "Student ID should not empty!"
}
```

Model Class

```
public class Example {


@SerializedName("school_id")
@Expose
private String schoolId;
@SerializedName("tabID")
@Expose
private String tabID;
@SerializedName("student_id")
@Expose
private String studentId;
@SerializedName("student_test_history_id")
@Expose
private String studentTestHistoryId;

@SerializedName("studentTestReports")
@Expose
private List<StudentTestReports> studentTestReports= null;



public String getSchoolId() {
    return schoolId;
}

public void setSchoolId(String schoolId) {
    this.schoolId = schoolId;
}

public String getTabID() {
    return tabID;
}

public void setTabID(String tabID) {
    this.tabID = tabID;
}

public String getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getStudentTestHistoryId() {
    return studentTestHistoryId;
}

public void setStudentTestHistoryId(String studentTestHistoryId) {
    this.studentTestHistoryId = studentTestHistoryId;
}

public List<StudentTestReports> getStudentTestReports() {
return studentTestReports;
}

public void setStudentTestReports(List<StudentTestReports> studentTestReports) {
this.studentTestReports = studentTestReports;
}

}



public class StudentTestReports{

@SerializedName("testId")
@Expose
private String testId;
@SerializedName("science")
@Expose
private String science;
@SerializedName("maths")
@Expose
private String maths;

public String gettestId() {
return position;
}

public void settestId(String testId) {
this.testId= testId;
}

public String getScience() {
return science;
}

public void setScience(String science) {
this.science = science;
}

public String getMaths() {
return maths;
}

public void setMaths(String maths) {
this.maths= maths;
}

}
```

API call through retrofit

```
/**
     *  Change Password Online
     */
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(WebServices. FULL_REPORT)
    Call<String> fullReport(@Field("school_id")String schoolId,
                                             @Field("tabID")String tabID,
                                             @Field("student_id")String studentId,
                                             @Field("student_test_history_id")String studenttestHistoryID,
                                             @Field("all_test_report")List paymentMode);






private void razorpayCallAfterPayment(String schoolId, String tabID, String studentId, String razorpayPaymentID, String paymentSuccess) {

        progressDialog.show();
        Call<AfterStudentTestPaymentModel> studentTestPaymentModelCall = webService.razorpayAfterPaymentSuccess(schoolId,tabID,studentId,razorpayPaymentID,paymentSuccess);
        studentTestPaymentModelCall .enqueue(new Callback<AfterStudentTestPaymentModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AfterStudentTestPaymentModel> call, Response<AfterStudentTestPaymentModel> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body().isStatus()) {


                    /*String sTestHisID=response.body().getResult().getStudentTestHistoryId();
                    editor.putString("pTestHisID_razor_pay", sTestHisID);
                    editor.commit();*/

                    //} else
                    Toasty.success(AmountCartActivity.this, ""+response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();



                    //sharePreferenceManager_addPatient.getUserLoginData(AddPatientModel.class).getResult().getPatientId().equalsIgnoreCase("");
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(AmountCartActivity.this, "Fail Status", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {

                    /**
                     *handling bad request 400 response
                     */
                    APIError apiError = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
                    Toasty.error(AmountCartActivity.this, ""+ apiError.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                    //askForLogout();
                }

                if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AfterStudentTestPaymentModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Toasty.error(AmountCartActivity.this, "Error occurred,Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
```

I have set the values in Example class and StudentTestReports this class is having testId's and its values. So, how do I send those values by using Json array through Retrofit2 Api call. And, i want to send different values through different testID's. I dont have any idea about it, so please help me.

Comment: Firstly, there is no Model class required for INPUT params, it's only required for OUTPUT. Secondly, the error is coming from the server, please check at server end if you are passing the data properly.

Comment: @Shruti B make your all variables in model class with same as API response.Because in retrofit all variable must be same as API response otherwise there will be error,your response will not save.

check this website:-" http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ " here you need to add your response and it will make POJO class and you need to just download this class. Don't need to check for same variables.

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån I just want to know can i send json array using list  through retrofit.   all_student_report: {"studentlist_id": "4",
                      "maths": "78",
                    },
             {"studentlist_id": "5",
                "Engish": "65",
                 "Science": "98"
        }    I want to send this report to server. How do I send this?

Comment: @pratikvekariya   I just want to know can i send json array using list  through retrofit.   all_student_report: {"studentlist_id": "4",
                      "maths": "78",
                    },
             {"studentlist_id": "5",
                "Engish": "65",
                 "Science": "98"
        }    I want to send this report to server. How do I send this?

Comment: @Shruti B you just need to call this method in your activity " Call<String> fullReport(here pass your parameters) " to send data